# Using TweenMax with filters created in the Flash IDE

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, filter, tween

Is there a way to get TweenMax to tween the filters of an DisplayObject **where The filters are added in the Flash IDE.**

I want to Tween between two states and it would be nice if I could do it without creating the two states with bitmaps and tween between them. One state with the filters and one without the filters.

```
// pseudo-code
var filterList : Array = _targetView.filters;
TweenMax.to(_targetView, 0.8, {/*insert filter tweens here*/})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so. The filters property is an Array of Filters (extending the BitmapFilter Class), as you know. Just access the filters by their position in the array and tween their values accordingly:

```
var dropShadow0: DropShadowFilter = _targetView.filters[0]
var dropShadow1: DropShadowFilter = _targetView.filters[1]

TweenMax.to(dropShadow0, 0.8, {strength: dropShadow1.strength})
```

Comment: The thing is that I don´t know what type of filter that is applied to the DisplayObject.